# Insert an array in postgresql database using vercel sql utility

Tags: next.js, vercel

```
  import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
  const aliases= ['uncle', 'joe'];
  await sql`INSERT INTO USER (aliases) VALUES ${aliases}`;
```

USER would be defined like this

```
CREATE TABLE USER ( aliases text[]);
```

This code would give me an error : Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Primitive'.

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify the array before making the insert,
eg:
`const aliases = JSON.stringify([...])`
then when you read simply parse the string
`const parseData = JSON.parse(aliases)`

Comment: I just added replace like this   `JSON.stringify(aliases).replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}")` and it worked. Can you update your answer so I can accept it plz ?